# Conditional rules for HTML5 form validation

Tags: html, webforms

I am wondering if it's possible to set an element "required" based on some other element state. For instance, say I have an input element that I want to be "required" if and only if the user checks a specific checkbox. First, is this possible to do it without the use of JavaScript? Second, if we use JavaScript, of course one could set up a rule / validation if the user checks that checkbox, but what about consistency regarding the default browser validation errors? Would it be "correct" to add the "required" attribute to the element once the checkbox is clicked? I don't see an alternative here. What are your thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this without javascript.

With javascript, you could do this easily enough.

I would add the `required` attribute only after the checkbox is clicked.

In fact, I would make this a `toggled` piece, so that the user can uncheck and unrequire the input.

However, I would not rely on browser's implementation of the `required` attribute. Instead, I would create my own required notification using some CSS (highlighting, animation, displaying some words).

Comment: "However, I would not rely on browser's implementation of the required attribute" - I agree! I am thinking, if I would use JavaScript I could solve my problem, but, if JavaScript is disabled (just assuming.. ), then I would have the browser default form validation for some fields but not for others. Unless (I should have mentioned this before) I have the "novalidation" in the HTML and this would be removed with JavaScript, which means that without JavaScript there would only be Server side validation..

Answer (score 0):

You may use polyfills to emulate native validation when not available:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: There are some scripts probably, but if JS is disabled, you will have validations for some fields and not for others..

Comment: Anyway, you have to do server-side validation. And you have to accept the fact that JS can be disabled, and that polyfills won't work in this case. But it can only improve the user experience, so why not do it ?