# HTML "required" only if radiobutton active

Tags: html, forms, input, radio-button, required

Currently i have 5 radiobuttons. 4 of them define an certain amount of money. The last one marks a custom field there you can enter a custom amount of money in an input field.

Is it possible, just with HTML, to set the input field "required" only if the the last radiobutton is active.

If it's not possible, is javascript the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do conditional validation of form fields with HTML only. At most you could manipulate the DOM with javascript to add the `required` attribute to the `<input>` element when necessary (i.e. in an `onchange` event handler for the radio button).

Remember it might be useful to provide fallback behavior for the `required` attribute for older browsers without HTML5 support.

<sub>Note: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10166168/851811) is pretty much about the same.</sub>

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, i will try it with javascript! As a fallback a have another validation in .php that validates the given values again.

Comment: @inf3ction Great, that's definitely the way to go. Don't ever rely on client-side validations only. Server-side validations are a must.